# Can one set different delay per item in caroufredsel?

Tags: caroufredsel

Is there a way when using the `auto` configuration in caroufredsel ([caroufredsel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/configuration.php)) to specify different delays per item so that for example one can have:

- 1st Item - 5 seconds
- 2nd Item - 10 seconds
- 3rd Item - 8 seconds
- ...

Comment: Do you have any exmaple? Ye it does...

Comment: @Unykvis, no I don't have an example.  How can one specify different slideshow delay per item from the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working on a website I had a similar problem. The carousel contains an animation and some additional information as static slides. The duration of the animation exceeds by far the time needed to read the content of the other slides, so I wanted to set a different timeout for the animation.

The solution is somewhat hidden in the documentation on the [code examles page for custom events](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/code-examples/custom-events.php) in the section *'the configuration-event'.*

You can access and edit the `configuration` object via

`$('#carousel').triggerHandler('configuration')`

and actually assign different `timeoutDuration` values depending on the item(s) to be shown, for example in the `onBefore` event handler of the `scroll` object:

```
...
scroll: {

    onBefore: function(data){

        if(data.items.visible[0].id == 'animation'){
            t = 30000;
        }
        else {
            t = 5000;
        }
        $('#carousel').triggerHandler('configuration').auto.timeoutDuration = t;
    },
...
```

Comment: This should do the job! Thanks for your insight :) I would store all such slide timeout durations in an array in JS and then attach with the onBefore event to update the timeout of the next transition! :)